# How to groupby a single column and print the same in excel using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

| username | places |
| --- | --- |
| john | new york |
| john | chicago |
| john | seattle |
| jack | washington |
| jack | dallas |
| kim | miami |
| natalie | san francisco |
| natalie | los angeles |

Now I would like to print in excel like this:

| username | places |
| --- | --- |
| john | new york |
|  | chicago |
|  | seattle |
| jack | washington |
|  | dallas |
| kim | miami |
| natalie | san francisco |
|  | los angeles |

So when I did

```
df.groupby("username")
```

And called `groups` on the above I am getting the same dataframe. Also I am trying to print the same in excel like this:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Users Places", index=False, startrow=1)
```

But I am getting the results as the first table. What am I doing wrong here? How to rectify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.sort_values('username').set_index(['username','places']).to_excel('etc.xlsx', sheet_name="Users Places")
```

output of excel file:

[image]

Comment: This works but for cases where again `john` is after `natalie` then i want even those repeated rows where john comes after some other rows to be grouped with the rows that are at the top. So basically group all rows of particular person together. Whether they come again in between or at the end. The above solution does not work for that case.

Comment: @user001 updated answer for those cases as well...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Yeah. Got it. One doubt. I have to sort only by `username` but for `set_index` why should we pass `places` also?

Comment: @user001 for making it multi index and saving it to excel to achieve your expected output...If you only make ''username as index then you doesn't get your expected output